# Adding Ozone to my sky simulation

Tags: c++, scattering

I implemented a simulation for the colour of the sky a while ago by following the scratch a pixel tutorial: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/procedural-generation-virtual-worlds/simulating-sky

I adapted it for the actual sun position and am able to get realistic sky colours during the day. However, I noticed that after sunset/ before sunrise, the colours are greyish when they should be deep blue. After researching about this, I read that this is due to the ozone absorption not being present in my model.

I used extinction coefficients : (3.426,8.298,0.356) * 0.06e-5 -> found on https://media.contentapi.ea.com/content/dam/eacom/frostbite/files/s2016-pbs-frostbite-sky-clouds-new.pdf

and also read that since the ozone does not scatter, it should only be added to the transmittance value.

[image: more info about ozone]

Therefore, I modified the code from scratchapixel as follows:

```
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
            vec3 samplePosition = ray_in2.origin() + (tCurrent + 
            segmentLength * 0.5f) * ray_in2.direction();
            float height = samplePosition.length() - atmosphere.earthRadius;

            // compute optical depth for light
            float hr = exp(-height / atmosphere.Hr) * segmentLength;
            float hm = exp(-height / atmosphere.Hm) * segmentLength;
            float ho = exp(-height / atmosphere.Hr)* segmentLength*(6e-7);
            opticalDepthR += hr;
            opticalDepthM += hm;
            opticalDepthO += ho;

            // light optical depth
            float t0Light, t1Light;

                ...
            for (j = 0; j < numSamplesLight; ++j) {
                vec3 samplePositionLight = samplePosition + (tCurrentLight + 
                segmentLengthLight * 0.5f) * sunDir;
                float heightLight = samplePositionLight.length() - 
                atmosphere.earthRadius;

                if (heightLight < 0) break;
                opticalDepthLightR += exp(-heightLight / atmosphere.Hr) * 
                segmentLengthLight;
                opticalDepthLightM += exp(-heightLight / atmosphere.Hm) * 
                segmentLengthLight;
                opticalDepthLightO += exp(-heightLight / atmosphere.Hr) * 
                segmentLengthLight*(6e-7); ;
                tCurrentLight += segmentLengthLight;
            }
            if (j == numSamplesLight) {
                vec3 tau = (betaR) * (opticalDepthR + opticalDepthLightR) + 
               betaM * 1.1f * (opticalDepthM + opticalDepthLightM)+ betaO*
              (opticalDepthO + opticalDepthLightO);
                vec3 attenuation(exp(-tau.x()), exp(-tau.y()), exp(-
                tau.z()));
```

summary : 
-I added variable opticalDepthO and opticalDepthLightO which are calculated same as the optical depth for Rayleigh, but multiplied by 6e-7.

-Then, the sum of opticalDepthLightO and opticalDepthO is multiplied by the extiction coefficient for ozone and added to variable tau.

Problem is, I see no difference in my sky colour before and after adding ozone. Can someone guide me to what it is that I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!